# Grails Dynamic Requestmaps with same URL values

Tags: grails, spring-security, http-method

Using Grails 2.4.3, Spring Security Core Plugin 2.0-RC4..

I have these requestmap entries in my database: (id, version, config_attribute, http_method, url)

```
 - '1', '0', 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER', 'GET', '/customer/**'
 - '2', '0', 'ROLE_ADMIN', NULL, '/customer/**'
```

All users with role `'ROLE_USER'` have no access to customer actions.

However, if I have these requestmaps instead:

```
 - '1', '0', 'ROLE_ADMIN', NULL, '/customer/**'
 - '2', '0', 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER', 'GET', '/customer/**'
```

Both users with role 'ROLE_ADMIN' or 'ROLE_USER' will only have GET access to customer actions.

What I want: all HttpMethods are allowed for admins, and only Http GET for normal users. How should I configure my requestmaps?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the http_method to `ANY` for `ROLE_ADMIN` and `GET` for `ROLE_USER` should do what want.

Comment: This is the httpmethod enum 

public enum HttpMethod {

 GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, TRACE

}

Will 'ANY' work?

Comment: That is what is used as the default http_method for the `@Secured` annotation.  See https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/62ab9045a8d68d3ff06f7b8f76a738ae43338c40/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/annotation/Secured.groovy#L39.

Comment: Your pointing me to a string but the RequestMap class uses the HttpMethod enum which don't have the 'ANY' value. I guess null == ANY?